# GNOME shell extensions got disabled on wake, can't re-enable

Tags: gnome, suspend, extension

I use a lot of extensions from the GNOME tweak tool, and normally when I sleep the laptop and wake up they are all still enabled and functioning. However just now when I woke up the laptop all of the extensions were disabled.

Further, when I go to the tweak tool and try to enable any extension, the button says ON yet the effect of the extension doesn't happen. If I close the tweak tool and reopen it the extension says OFF again.

This is the second time this has happened, the first time I rebooted to fix it.

I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.3 64-bit.

Edit:
Even trying to enable an extension from the terminal fails, it says "'extension' is now enabled." yet the extension doesn't work. Trying the command agains says "'extension' is already enabled."

Comment: Try restarting the shell by alt+f2, then R+return/enter

Comment: Thanks, that worked and also automatically re-enabled all of the extensions. Any idea what the issue is and how to prevent it from happening again though?

Comment: Have you removed any extension using GNOME Tweak Tool? If so, you might be experiencing this bug: http://pad.lv/1681918.

Comment: No I haven't removed any extension.